# Problems with dependencies for The Witcher 2 - Ubuntu 16.10 x64

Tags: package-management, dependencies, 16.10

I have problems with launching or editing the settings of **The Witcher 2: Assassins Of Kings Enhanced Edition**. Every time I try to launch it, it just pops up a window with dependencies problems:

[image: xwindow - dependencies problems screenshot]

Can anybody tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please consider providing text outputs instead of screenshots. It helps finding the question and improves formatting. Thanks

Comment: Did the advice below fix the problem for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following command in Terminal (you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open the Terminal and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste in the Terminal):

```
sudo apt install libc6:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-data:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libsdl2-image-2.0-0:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libcurl3:i386
```

Make sure it doesn't try to remove any crucial packages like your window manager. It might list some packages under 'The following packages will be removed:' before it says 'Do you want to continue? [Y/n]'.

<sub>[Source](https://www.gog.com/game/the_witcher_2) (search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) for dependencies) 

[Source](https://www.gog.com/forum/the_witcher_2/witcher2_failed_to_start_due_to_following_dependency_problems) that said you might need to install dependencies</sub>

Comment: It has removed VirtualBox for me. And still not starting. Lights off.